# Best practice for providing optional functions for a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mixins, python-class

Currently I am writing a Python program with a plugin system. To develop a new plugin a new class must be created and inherit from a base plugin class. Now it should be possible to add optional functions via mixins. Some mixins provide new functions others access builtin types of the base class and can act with them or change them.

In the following a simplified structure:

```
import abc
import threading

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = dict()

        if hasattr(self, "edit_config"):
            self.edit_config()

     def start(self):
        """Starts the Plugin"""
        if hasattr(self, "loop"):
            self._loop()

class AMixin:
    def edit_config(self):
        self.config["foo"] = 123

class BMixin(abc.ABC):
    def _loop(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True)
        thread.start()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def loop(self):
        """Override this method with a while true loop to establish a ongoing loop
        """
        pass

class NewPlugin(Base, AMixin, BMixin):
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            print("Hello")

 plugin = NewPlugin()
 plugin.start()
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

EDIT: I need to make my question more specific. The question is whether the above is the Pythonic way and is it possible to ensure that the mixin are inherited exclusively in conjunction with the Base class. Additionally it would be good in an IDE like VSCode to get support for e.g. autocomplete when accessing builtin types of the Base class, like in AMixin, without inheriting from it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow but not require subclasses to define some behaviour in a method called by the base class, the simplest way is to declare the method in the base class, have an empty implementation, and just call the method unconditionally. This way you don't have to check whether the method exists before calling it.

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = dict()
        self.edit_config()
    
    def start(self):
        self.loop()
    
    def edit_config(self):
        pass
    
    def loop(self):
        pass

class AMixin:
    def edit_config(self):
        self.config["foo"] = 123

class NewPlugin(AMixin, Base):
    def loop(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print("Hello")
```

Note that you have to write `AMixin` before `Base` in the list of superclasses, so that its `edit_config` method overrides the one from `Base`, and not the other way around. You can avoid this by writing `class AMixin(Base):` so that `AMixin.edit_config` always overrides `Base.edit_config` in the method resolution order.

If you want to require subclasses to implement one of the methods, then you can `raise TypeError()` instead of `pass` in the base class's method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and good tips. So you can say that I am basically on the right track. It was important for me to find out whether it is a common/pythonic way. For my personal feeling, I would still prefer to leave the optional functions only in the mixins and check in the base class whether they are available.

Comment: I'd suggest going with an empty method on the base class - another reason is that you probably want each mixin's `edit_config` method to call `super().edit_config()` so that multiple mixins can each add some behaviour.

Comment: Yes right. That is absolutely what I have in mind. So that different methods call the same method. You have helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would move the calls to the methods provided by the mix-ins to `__init__` methods defined by those classes.

```
import abc
import threading


class Base:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(**kwargs)
        self.config = dict()


class AMixin:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.edit_config()

    def edit_config(self):
        self.config["foo"] = 123


class BMixin(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs):
        self.loop()

    def _loop(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.loop, daemon=True)
        thread.start()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def loop(self):
        """Override this method with a while true loop to establish a ongoing loop
        """
        pass

class NewPlugin(Base, AMixin, BMixin):
    pass
```

When you instantiate a concrete subclass of `NewPlugin`, `Base.__init__`, `AMixin.__init__`, and `BMixin.__init__` will be called in that order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The architecture of the base class is a bit more complex than in the simplified example. This means that it is necessary to execute certain mixin functions outside of __init__(). For example, only when starting the plugin.

Comment: This will still work given your edit. The call to `self.loop()` in `BMixin.__init__` doesn't mean that `BMixin.loop` will be called. If `self` has type`NewPlugin`, then `self.loop` resolves to `NewPlugin.loop`, not `BMixin.loop`.

Comment: I have changed the question and the example code again to clarify my question. 
Regarding your answer: As for BMixin I think I understand your explanation. But if I run self.edit_confg() already in the __init__() of AMixin the value in self.config["foo"] is already set to 123. What if because of the architecture the value should be changed first in e.g. self.start()? Have I explained my worries correctly?

Comment: For `BMixin`, just override `start` instead of `__init__`, using `super`.